# Not able to select radio button: issue with z-index?

Tags: html, css

I am observing this strange behavior with the radio buttons. Whenever I set the z-index of the parent div I am not able to select the radio buttons.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/x7rm63n9/2/. Try to select the buttons inside the main box.

The css style for the main div is:

```
.main_box
{
 position: relative;
 background-color: #444;
 width: 65%;
 margin: 30px auto;
 height: 450px;
 z-index: -6;     /* IF I REMOVE THIS LINE I CAN SELECT THE RADIO BUTTONS*/
 border: 12px solid #fff;
}
```

Why is this happening? Is there any workaround for this without changing z-index?

I tried to set up the simple demo. (http://jsfiddle.net/juruf6a8/1/) It works fine here.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You have set a `z-index` of `-6` so your content is _below_ the body and so cant be clicked. Why do you need negative `z-index`'s?

Comment: as you can see I need to get the title div on the main box. Also I have two other divs producing shadow effect at the bottom of the main box. So using z-indexes

Comment: @Moobs How does it works in the demo link? there also I have set the z-index of -6

Comment: If you inspect the body element in your second example you will see that it has collapsed to the height of `.main` and so isn't covering your inputs. This is because `.innerDiv` is using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this I have made the update and it is working on my end.
http://jsfiddle.net/x7rm63n9/4/

Here is what you have to do:

-remove the z-index:-6 of the "main-box" div

-wrap the banner div inside another div called "banner-container" and write this code for it

```
.banner-container{
    z-index:1;
    position:relative;
}
.banner-container:after{
    clear:both;
    content:'';
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: Superb answer. Thanks @Muhammad. Can you please tell what is the logic behind this? Thanks.

Comment: Please, call me Ameen :) I inspected your code with firebug and from that I found out that the banner did not have a proper layout. If you inspect ur code with firebug and then inspect the code which I did you can see that the difference. Since the banner was already using before and after another div was imp. for creating a layout. By using :after, I created a layout which wrapped the whole banner including its before and after and by using the z-index and position I placed the whole of the banner on top of the main block

Answer (score 0):

You could just make the radio buttons that are inside main_box higher if you **must** keep the z-index of -6 on the main_box itself.

```
.main_box, input[type=radio]
{
  z-index:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x7rm63n9/3/